# Will a buck converter allow current to pass through if Vin is less than the configured output voltage?

Tags: buck, switching-regulator, texas-instruments, step-down

In general, will a buck converter allow current to pass through if Vin is less than the configured output voltage?

Specifically, I'm reading the [TPS54308](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54308.pdf) datasheet and I'm not seeing an answer to my question.

Comment: Some bucks do, but some may have  an under-voltage lockout circuit (UVLO).

Comment: Yes , UVLO is the designer’s responsibility

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that Under Voltage Lock Out (UVLO) was the term I was concerned with.

Comment: A "portable" two-way radio system I once worked with had a battery pack that could be charged from the cigarette lighter of a vehicle.  It could also be charged from a powersupply.  Users complained that they would charge the radios overnight, get in the truck with a radio, and drive to a work site - radio battery is suddenly empty.  They were plugging the radio in to charge in the truck, then starting the truck.  The charger for the battery pack was a switching power supply the had no UVLO.  The radio battery pack was accidentally being used as a booster to start the truck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, many Buck regulators (including the TPS54308) will do this. As long as the input voltage doesn't trip a UVLO protection (either internal to the chip or part of your circuit), it will pass through at 100% duty cycle trying to reach the desired output voltage. If you want a higher cutoff voltage than the chip provides, you'll need an external circuit to measure the input and drive the EN pin accordingly.

From your datasheet:

[image: UVLO specs]

Comment: Based on the excerpt in your answer and section 7.3.5 of the same document, it seems like I can configure a higher UVLO value using the EN pin, but I cannot go below the internally configured for UVLO value for the Vin pin, correct?

Comment: Right. If your VIN drops to say, 3.0V, it's going to shut off no matter what. If you wanted a cutoff of 5V you could set up a comparator with the output going to the EN pin. The frequent hurdle there is having some other supply rail to compare to.

Comment: It looks like the en has a specific cutoff voltage so you don't need a comparator. Just put a voltage divider on Vin and feed the output to en. Data sheet explains it.

Comment: Please, specify that this answer is specific to the TPS54308. There is no general answer for each buck converter, some have 100% duty, some have not.